# ImportError: No module named 'vtkRenderingFreeTypePython' - Vtk with Anaconda and Pycharm

Tags: vtk

I am getting this error while trying to run vtk in pycharm with an anaconda enviroment:

```
ImportError: No module named 'vtkRenderingFreeTypePython'
```

So far to fix the issue I have tried:

- Launching pycharm from the anaconda prompt with my environment
  activated.
- Using `pip install vtk` to download V8.1.2 of vtk. I previously had an 
  environment in which I got vtk working in pycharm, but it was a few months a go and I can't remember
  what I did. The difference I have found 
  between the environments is when I type `conda list vtk`. I found that my old one had V8.1.2 of vtk
  from the PyPi channel and the new one I have created has V 8.2.0.
    However this doesn't seem to fix the problem/change the version in the environment. I saw that vtk 
  8.1.2 is being installed in my ananconda3/lib folder, but not in any environments.

I am not sure if the old environment possibly has two different
     versions of vtk, because when I manage to run the program
     successfully I get this following warning:

```
 WARNING: Imported VTK version (8.1) does not match the one used
    to build the TVTK classes (8.2). This may cause problems.
    Please rebuild TVTK.
```

I have read lots on the internet about this problem being a bug with pycharm, and that there's no way to fix it, but I know for a fact that it's possible as I have seen it working myself!

Overall I am at a loss for what to try next, so any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you DanielSchroederDev for editing my question! I wrote it in a little bit of a rush during a meeting so it definitely needed a tidy up.

I have been doing a bit of playing around and have found a solution that appears to work. Whether or not it will cause further problems down the line I cannot say.

1. Firstly, open the anaconda prompt and activate your environment
2. Type `pip install vtk`
3. Type `conda install mayavi` (if you want to use mayavi)
4. Now navigate to your ananconda folder. For me this is located at `c:\Users\ 
   <UserName>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`
5. Within this folder, there should be a directory `Lib\Site-Packages\vtk` Copy this 
   folder to the clipboard.
6. Now go back up to the anaconda folder and go to `envs\<env_name>\Lib\Site_Packages`
   and paste.
7. Now you should be able to use vtk, but may get the warning I described in the 
   question. I believe the reason I was getting the warning was because I also want to
   use mayavi, which requires the new version of vtk. This means that two versions are 
   being used at once.

I know it is far from an ideal solution. I am not aware of a neater way to solve the problem, so if anybody has a better way then I'd like to hear it!

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have any `vtk` folder, nor in the base nor in the virtual environment folders.